Unable to use Object Layer from a Tiled Map with Python Arcade
I am trying to make a top down game with Python Arcade and I'm using Tiled to create a basic map so I can get the code working. I have a basic "Ground" layer and an object layer called "Walls" I am going to use for collision detection. The problem is, when I am trying create a PhysicsEngineSimple() in arcade i keep getting the error:

arcade.scene.SceneKeyError: "This scene does not contain a SpriteList named 'Walls'."

I have checked through arcade.Scene() code and it looks like the Tile Layers are added to a sprite_list and the Object layers are put into an object_list.
When creating the physics engine, I pass in the Scene with the Layer_options "Walls" but the Scene object doesn't have "Walls" as a SpriteList because It's in an ObjectList. arcade.PhysicsEngineSimple() only iterates through the sprite_list.
Here's my code:
class MyGame(arcade.Window):
def __init__(self, width, height, title):
    super().__init__(width, height, title)

    self.player = Player(center_x=1280 / 2, center_y=720 / 2, scale=1)

    self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
    self.player_list.append(self.player)

    # TileMap Object
    self.tile_map = None

    # Name of map file to load
    map_name = "maps/dungeon.tmx"

    # Layer specific options are defined based on Layer names in a dictionary
    layer_options = {
        "Walls": {
            "use_spatial_hash": True,
        },
    }

    # Read in the tiled map
    self.tile_map = arcade.load_tilemap(map_name, 3, layer_options)

    # Scene Object
    self.scene = None

    # Initialize Scene with our TileMap, this will automatically add all layers

    # from the map as SpriteLists in the scene in the proper order.
    self.scene = arcade.Scene.from_tilemap(self.tile_map)

    # Physics engine
    self.physics_engine = None
    # --- Other stuff

    # Create the 'physics engine'
    self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEngineSimple(
        self.player,
        walls=self.scene["Walls"]
    )

def on_draw(self):
    self.clear()

    # Draw our Scene
    self.scene.draw()
    self.player_list.draw()

def on_update(self, delta_time):
    self.player.update()
    self.player.update_animation()

def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
    if key == arcade.key.UP or key == arcade.key.W:
        self.player.change_y = 5
    elif key == arcade.key.LEFT or key == arcade.key.A:
        self.player.change_x = -5
    elif key == arcade.key.DOWN or key == arcade.key.S:
        self.player.change_y = -5
    elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT or key == arcade.key.D:
        self.player.change_x = 5
    elif key == arcade.key.SPACE:
        self.player.change_state(PlayerState.DIE)
        self.player.change_x = 0
        self.player.change_y = 0

def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
    if key == arcade.key.UP or key == arcade.key.W:
        self.player.change_y = 0
    elif key == arcade.key.LEFT or key == arcade.key.A:
        self.player.change_x = 0
    elif key == arcade.key.DOWN or key == arcade.key.S:
        self.player.change_y = 0
    elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT or key == arcade.key.D:
        self.player.change_x = 0
    elif key == arcade.key.SPACE:
        self.player.change_state(PlayerState.DIE)
        # pass

Any advice on getting arcade.PhysicsEngineSimple() to see the object_list will be greatly appreciated. Without it, I can't load any collision information.
I am using Arcade 3.0.0.dev32 with PyCharm

Can you share dungeon.tmx file?

@Alderven All the code is at the link below. The dungeon.tmx file is in the Maps folder

[link] https://github.com/eezageeza1976/Arcade

You need to create Tile Layer called Walls. Instead you've created Object Layer:

I've added Tile Layer called Walls and was able to run your game:


Thanks for the help it works for me as well now. The problem now is that i can walk straight through the walls. The object layer held the data for collisions, and I used '"use_spatial_hash": True' for collision detection but now I've made it a 'Tile Layer' it doesn't seem to detect a collision. I think now there is something wrong with the code.

I have found out where I was going wrong! I was updating [self.player.update()] but I wasn't updating the physics engine. I have added [self.physics_engine.update()] to the [on_update()] call and my player sprite now collides with the walls. Thanks for all your help.
